# Как открыть JSP страницу при использовании AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

подскажите пожалуйста:
Использую AJAX и посылаю/получаю ответ от сервлета, есть такой вариант что от сервера может придти JSP, но проблема в том, что страница не открывается, я могу через консоль браузера просмотреть response сервера - и там полноценная страница, но почему то браузер её не открывает.

[image]

В самом JS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как ты понял, что браузер не отображает разметку? Ты пробовал ее запихнуть в innerHtml какого-нибудь компонента?

Comment: Я от JSP(он же потом сервлет) отправляю ответ клиенту...в клиенте пробую отлавливать xhr.response и вывожу в консоль - вижу полноценную html страницу. Вот только я не пойму как заставить открыть страницу с этой разметкой

Comment: Вытяни контейнер по классу, допустим через document.querySelector(".container"). И в свойство innerHtml этого контейнера вставь то, что вернул сервер (свою разметку)

Comment: хм) хорошая идея, только получится что <html> тегов 2 пары будет, или же в JSP откидывать все стандартые теги и оставлять только то что будет встраиваться

Comment: а не подскажите ? как бы сделать, что бы браузер понимал что ему вернулась станица и её нужно открыть...

Comment: Насколько я знаю, никак. А какая вообще задача у тебя? Почему просто в урл пользователь не может набрать нужный адрес?

Comment: Уже дня 2 сижу с этой проблемой)
Мне нужно что бы была страница входа, пользователь вводит данные и отправляет на сервлет через AJAX запрос - если тако пользователь не найден, вернётся код ошибки и пользователю без перезагрузки покажется ошибка "что такого пользователя не существует". Если всё ОК - то пользователя кинет на JSP страницу "cabinet.jsp". Сейчас вот что: если я отправлю данные на сервер с формы входа, а потом ручками введу адресс до JSP - она открывается... а редиректить меня не хочет

Comment: А зачем так сложно. Можно ведь просто средствами jsp это сделать. Зачем использовать AJAX. P.S Чтобы сделать редирект, можно использовать window.location.href = "<твой урл>"

Comment: Сделаю проще как вы советуете) Спасибо огромное за помощь!)